# Entity Framework Core: Nested Many to Many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I started to use Entity Framework Core in a new project, and so far with a little help the database structure (with it's relationships) worked out fine.
I now encountered a situation which I cannot get to work in Entity Framework Core. I will try to describe the current Entities and their relations, and the situation that does not work.

In the project you can manage `Tags` with nested `TagValueCategories` and their nested `TagValues`. I can get all `Tags` and their nested properties using the below code:

```cs
databaseContext.Tags
    .Include(tag => tag.TagValueCategories)
        .ThenInclude(tagValueCategory => tagValueCategory.TagValues);
```

This works great and as expected.

In the project you can also manage `Files`. A `File` contains multiple properties and can contain specific selected `Tags` and optionally `TagValues`.
So for example `FileA.png` can contain the tag `Animal` and tagvalues `Dog` and `Cat`.

I have used the below entity `FileTag` to make it possible to store the `Tags` and `TagValues` related to a `File`. This also works, but reading the data from the database is not as friendly as I would like.

For example I cannot do this, which is the situation I would like to achieve:

```cs
databaseContext.Files
    .Include(file => file.Tags)
        .ThenInclude(tag => tag.TagValueCategories)
            .ThenInclude(tagValueCategory => tagValueCategory.TagValues);
```

In the current situation I can read the related `Tags` from a `File` but the output is not as desired:

```
File > FileTags > Tag
       FileTags > TagValue

The above Animals example would result in 2 records:
File: FileA.png, Tag: Animals, TagValue: Dog
File: FileA.png, Tag: Animals, TagValue: Cat
```

From testing and troubleshooting the current situation I now know that the `FileTag` entity way will not work for my desired situation.

Is there anyone that ever had to create a similar structure? Or does anyone know how to get to the desired situation?

```cs
public class FileTagEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<FileTag>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<FileTag> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(fileTag => fileTag.Id);
        builder.HasIndex(fileTag => new { fileTag.FileId, fileTag.TagId, fileTag.TagValueId });

        builder.HasOne<File>(fileTag => fileTag.File)
            .WithMany(file => file.Tags)
            .HasForeignKey(fileTag => fileTag.FileId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        builder.HasOne<Tag>(fileTag => fileTag.Tag)
            .WithMany(tag => tag.FileTags)
            .HasForeignKey(fileTag => fileTag.TagId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

        builder.HasOne<TagValue>(fileTag => fileTag.TagValue)
            .WithMany(tagValue => tagValue.FileTags)
            .HasForeignKey(fileTag => fileTag.TagValueId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

        builder.Property(fileTags => fileTags.TagValueId)
            .IsRequired(false);
    }
}
```

```cs
[EntityTypeConfiguration(typeof(FileTagEntityTypeConfiguration))]
public class FileTag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public required int FileId { get; set; }
    public virtual required File File { get; set; }

    public required int TagId { get; set; }
    public virtual required Tag Tag { get; set; }

    public int? TagValueId { get; set; }
    public virtual TagValue? TagValue { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class File
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<FileTag> Tags { get; set; } = new List<FileTag>();
}
```

```cs
public class Tag : ITagContent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public virtual ICollection<FileTag> FileTags { get; set; }
    
    public virtual ICollection<TagValueCategory> TagValueCategories { get; set; } = new List<TagValueCategory>();
}
```

```cs
[Index(nameof(Name), nameof(TagId), IsUnique = true)]
public class TagValueCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(255)]
    public required string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TagValue> TagValues { get; set; } = new List<TagValue>();

    public virtual int TagId { get; set; }
    public virtual required Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
[Index(nameof(Name), nameof(TagValueCategoryId), IsUnique = true)]
public class TagValue
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(255)]
    public required string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual int TagValueCategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual TagValueCategory TagValueCategory { get; set; }
    
    public virtual ICollection<FileTag> FileTags { get; set; }
}
```

---

After changing the code and database layout according to @vonc his answer I have come to the following:

https://imgur.com/a/LzAvLUz
https://imgur.com/a/PzijMgn

Overall the structure is the same as before, but now the `Tag` and `TagValue` entities are in a separate list and table.

This still does not fix the original reason for my question though. One of the mayor downsides I have with use of Relationship Entities is the output.

The desired output is:

```json
{
    "files": [
        {
            "id": 717,
            "name": "file1.jpg",
            "tags": [
                {
                    "id": 262,
                    "name": "product",
                    "tagValueCategories": [
                        {
                            "id": 1,
                            "name": "Category 1",
                            "tagValues": [
                                {
                                    "id": 11105,
                                    "name": "Value 1"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 2,
                            "name": "Category 2",
                            "tagValues": [
                                {
                                    "id": 11115,
                                    "name": "Value 1"
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": 11108,
                                    "name": "Value 2"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But I currently get the following output:

```json
{
    "files": [
        {
            "id": 717,
            "name": "file1.jpg",
            "tags": [
                {
                    "tag": {
                        "id": 289,
                        "name": "Tag without TagValues",
                        "tagValueCategories": [
                            {
                                "id": 289,
                                "name": "Uncategorized",
                                "tagValues": []
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "tagValues": [
                {
                    "tagValue": {
                        "id": 11105,
                        "name": "Value 1",
                        "tagValueCategory": {
                            "id": 1,
                            "name": "Category 1"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "tagValue": {
                        "id": 11115,
                        "name": "Value 1",
                        "tagValueCategory": {
                            "id": 2,
                            "name": "Category 2"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "tagValue": {
                        "id": 11108,
                        "name": "Value 2",
                        "tagValueCategory": {
                            "id": 2,
                            "name": "Category 2"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to keep the Relationshop Entities, but somehow make the output reflect the `desired output` above?

Comment: Than can be normalized to 3rd normal form

Comment: Also the entity type builder configuration for the M:N (FileTag) table is missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on [jmvcollaborator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13579714/jmvcollaborator)'s comments, normalization is a database design technique that reduces data redundancy and eliminates undesirable characteristics like insertion, update, and deletion anomalies. In a normalized model, data that logically constitutes a single unit is stored in a single table.
See also "[Understanding Database Normalization with Example](https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/sqlserver/database-normalization-basics) " from [Shailendra Chauhan](https://www.dotnettricks.com/mentors/shailendra-chauhan) .

In your original model, you stored data that describes the relationship between a `File` and a `Tag` in the `FileTag` entity, but you also included `TagValueId`, which belongs to a separate logical unit - the relationship between a `Tag` and its `TagValues`. Including `TagValueId` in the `FileTag` entity essentially denormalizes the data, because it mingles data from two different logical units in a single table.

It would be better to rename `FileTag` in `FileTagValue`, an entity which now describes the relationship between a `File` and a `TagValue`, as a single logical unit. The `TagValueId` logically belongs in this table because it is part of the same unit.
The new name makes it clear that this entity represents the relationship between a `File` and a `TagValue`, not between a `File` and a `Tag`. By convention, the name of a join table (which is what `FileTagValue` is) often combines the names of the two main entities it connects.

```cs
// Renamed from FileTag to FileTagValue. Now it relates File and TagValue (not File and Tag).
public class FileTagValue
{
    // The primary key of FileTagValue is a composite key consisting of FileId and TagValueId.
    public int FileId { get; set; }
    public File File { get; set; }
    public int TagValueId { get; set; }
    public TagValue TagValue { get; set; }
}
```

The `File` entity remains largely the same, the navigation property now points to `FileTagValue`.

```cs
public class File
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    // Changed from ICollection<FileTag> Tags to ICollection<FileTagValue> TagValues
    // That is because we now want to relate File to TagValue (not Tag).
    public ICollection<FileTagValue> TagValues { get; set; } = new List<FileTagValue>();
}
```

But: this change in model design implies that a `File` can only be associated with a `Tag` through a `TagValue`. If you need to be able to associate a `File` with a `Tag` directly (without a `TagValue`), you will need a separate many-to-many relationship between `File` and `Tag`.

You need to add a `navigation` property to `FileTagValue` in `TagValue` entity

```cs
public class TagValue
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int TagValueCategoryId { get; set; }
    public TagValueCategory TagValueCategory { get; set; }

    // That navigation property was added to establish a many-to-many relationship between TagValue and File.
    public ICollection<FileTagValue> Files { get; set; } = new List<FileTagValue>();
}
```

The `TagValueCategory` and `Tag` are unchanged.

The `FileTagEntityTypeConfiguration` becomes a `FileTagValueEntityTypeConfiguration`, an [EF Fluent API](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/fluent-api-in-entity-framework-core.aspx), which will help to establish the many-to-many relationship between `File` and `TagValue` entities.

In Entity Framework Core, a [many-to-many relationship](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-ef-core.aspx) can be represented using a join entity that includes foreign keys for each of the entities involved in the relationship. In this case, `FileTagValue` is the join entity that represents the many-to-many relationship between `File` and `TagValue`.

The `FileTagValueEntityTypeConfiguration` class is where you configure the relationship. Specifically, it is where you:

- Define a composite key for `FileTagValue` that consists of the foreign keys `FileId` and `TagValueId`.
- Set up a one-to-many relationship between `File` and `FileTagValue`.
- Set up a one-to-many relationship between `TagValue` and `FileTagValue`.

The combination of these one-to-many relationships effectively creates the desired many-to-many relationship between `File` and `TagValue`.

```cs
public class FileTagValueEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<FileTagValue>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<FileTagValue> builder)
    {
        // The primary key is a combination of FileId and TagValueId. No TagId is involved now.
        builder.HasKey(fileTagValue => new { fileTagValue.FileId, fileTagValue.TagValueId });

        // Setting up the one-to-many relationship from File to FileTagValue.
        builder.HasOne(fileTagValue => fileTagValue.File)
            .WithMany(file => file.TagValues)
            .HasForeignKey(fileTagValue => fileTagValue.FileId);

        // Setting up the one-to-many relationship from TagValue to FileTagValue.
        builder.HasOne(fileTagValue => fileTagValue.TagValue)
            .WithMany(tagValue => tagValue.Files)
            .HasForeignKey(fileTagValue => fileTagValue.TagValueId);
    }
}
```

That updated model reflects a direct many-to-many relationship between `File` and `TagValue`, which enables you to use the [`Include`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.include?view=efcore-7.0) and [`ThenInclude`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.theninclude?view=efcore-7.0) methods to pull in the related `TagValueCategory` and `TagValues` when querying `Files`.

After making these changes, you can then run the query as you have mentioned:

```cs
databaseContext.Files
    .Include(file => file.TagValues)
        .ThenInclude(fileTagValue => fileTagValue.TagValue)
            .ThenInclude(tagValue => tagValue.TagValueCategory)
                .ThenInclude(tagValueCategory => tagValueCategory.TagValues);
```

But that supposes to update your database schema to reflect these changes. If you are using [EF Core migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli), you can generate a new migration and apply it to the database.

---

Given your expected output, this is more related to how you are serializing the data for output rather than how the data is structured in your database or accessed via Entity Framework.

Entity Framework will load the data based on the relationships that you have defined and that data will be structured according to your entity definitions. The output format, however, is something that you control when you serialize the data.

From your desired output, it seems you want to include `Tag` and `TagValue` objects directly within your `File` objects rather than having them in separate lists.
To achieve this, you could create a custom **DTO (Data Transfer Object)** that represents the structure you want to output, and map your entity objects to this DTO. (as in "[Create Data Transfer Objects (DTOs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5)")

Entities represent your data model and are used to interact with the database.
DTOs are used to control the shape of your data when sending it to the client.

For instance, based on your desired output:

```cs
public class FileDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<TagDto> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class TagDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<TagValueCategoryDto> TagValueCategories { get; set; }
}

public class TagValueCategoryDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<TagValueDto> TagValues { get; set; }
}

public class TagValueDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

That does not require modifying your entity classes, as DTOs are separate from your entities and are used to shape your output data. You would typically populate these DTOs in your service layer or in your controller actions after retrieving and processing your data.

You would then map your entity data to these DTOs before serializing:

```cs
var files = dbContext.Files
    .Include(f => f.TagValues)
        .ThenInclude(ftv => ftv.TagValue)
            .ThenInclude(tv => tv.TagValueCategory)
                .ThenInclude(tvc => tvc.Tag)
    .ToList();

var fileDtos = files.Select(f => new FileDto
{
    Id = f.Id,
    Name = f.Name,
    Tags = f.TagValues
        .GroupBy(ftv => ftv.TagValue.TagValueCategory.Tag)
        .Select(g => new TagDto
        {
            Id = g.Key.Id,
            Name = g.Key.Name,
            TagValueCategories = g
                .GroupBy(ftv => ftv.TagValue.TagValueCategory)
                .Select(g2 => new TagValueCategoryDto
                {
                    Id = g2.Key.Id,
                    Name = g2.Key.Name,
                    TagValues = g2.Select(ftv => new TagValueDto
                    {
                        Id = ftv.TagValue.Id,
                        Name = ftv.TagValue.Name
                    })
                    .ToList()
                })
                .ToList()
        })
        .ToList()
})
.ToList();
```

Just keep in mind that this will load all the `TagValues` for each `File`, regardless of whether they will be used in the DTO or not. This could potentially consume more memory, especially if you have a large number of TagValues.

Based on the modified structure, the equivalent of the requested statement would look like this:

```cs
databaseContext.Files
    .Include(file => file.TagValues)
        .ThenInclude(fileTagValue => fileTagValue.TagValue)
            .ThenInclude(tagValue => tagValue.TagValueCategory)
                .ThenInclude(tagValueCategory => tagValueCategory.Tag);
```

This will load the `Files` with all the associated `FileTagValues`, `TagValues`, `TagValueCategories`, and `Tags`.

Comment: I have expanded my original question to include the results after trying your suggestions..

Answer (score 0):

```
databaseContext.Files
    .Include(file => file.Tags)
        .ThenInclude(tag => tag.TagValueCategories)
            .ThenInclude(tagValueCategory => tagValueCategory.TagValues);
```

This code is not set with your relations!!!
`FileTag` class does not have relation to `TagValueCategory` class!
and this code **never work**

use it instead and fix again your relation if you want

```
List<File> query = context.Files.Include(file => file.Tags)
    .ThenInclude(tag => tag.TagValue).ThenInclude(Value => Value.TagValueCategory).ToList();
```